# Windows 11 annoying feature - type a letter inserts it into the search bar instead of navigating the list

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

I am in folder "Details" view;
With Windows 10, if the folders are sorted alphabetically, say starting with A at the top, and I want to see folders/files starting with R further down, all I have to do is type R key on the keyboard, and the folders (or files) starting with R come into view;

With Windows 11, as soon as I type R, it inserts it into the Search bar, top right hand side , as if I asked it to do a search; NO, thank you very much - help me get the old behavior back!!
[image]

Comment: On my systems, if Explorer is not open, typing on the screen does not do anything. Only if Explorer is open does typing a letter go to the Explorer search. That is the way Windows 11 works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour can easily be changed: Open the File Explorer options, which are called "Folder Options" (from the File Explorer menu with three dots, see your screenshot), select the View tab, then "When typing into list view" and there "Select the typed Item in the view".

These options are also available in Win 10, but had a different default.

[image: Folder Options]